# Unable to find witten file in a webapplication (tomcat, Spring MVC)

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, io, jfreechart

I'm using JFreeChart to generate some reporting in my web application, I use JFreechart to build the chart and save it as an image, but I have never found that image in my Tomcat directory.

I tried to print the working directory, and it gives me the Tomcat root, so I'm wondering why the image is never written in that directory.

Here is my Service method:

```
public DefaultPieDataset generateChartEquipementsByDepartementDataset(){
    DefaultPieDataset pieDataset ;
    pieDataset = convertMapToDataset(reportsDao.getEquipementsByDepartementDataset()) ;
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(
            "% Equipements par departement",
            pieDataset,
            true,
            true,
            false
            ) ;
    try{
    ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new File("/chart.jpeg"), chart, 400, 400) ;
    }catch(Exception ex){}

    return pieDataset ;
}
```

When I test it, it writes the image in the root of my application, but never in tomcat.
Here is the controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/reports")
public String reportsHandler( Model model ) {
    reportingService.generateChartEquipementsByDepartementDataset() ;
    String curSession = System.getProperty("user.dir") ;
    model.addAttribute("curSession", curSession) ;
    return "home" ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root ( `/` ) doesn't point to the root path of the web app, you need to get a "translated path", by using [ServletContext.getRealPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29), like

```
... new File(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/chart.jpeg")) ....
```

Comment: It gives me the same result.
`@Autowired private ServletContext context ;`
`String curSession = context.getRealPath("/") ;`

Comment: I have a hard time believing that - can you post the code that uses getRealPath?

Comment: you're right, I didn't reload the application, now it gives me the root of my application in tomcat directory. but still no images there ..

Comment: The code above doesn't call getRealPath - you have to use that function to "correct" the path you give to File.

Answer (score 1):

Your throwing away your exception.  Change that to either not catch it or, at the very least, log it to see what's going on.

I suspect you have a permissions problem when attempting to write to that directory.